With Action Cable, test that many messages are broadcast
I know that I can test that an Action Cable message is broadcast like so:
expect {
  ActionCable.server.broadcast "messages", text: 'Hi!'
}.to have_broadcasted_to("messages").with(text: 'Hi!')

I am testing a module that, as one of its required side effects, should broadcast several messages. I want to be able to assert that the messages contain certain information. What is the best idiom to do so?
I want to write a test that does this, but I'm confident that this is not idiomatic:
result = expect { function_i_am_testing() }

result.to have_broadcasted_to("channel").with("Expected message 1")
result.to have_broadcasted_to("channel").with("Expected message 2")
result.to have_broadcasted_to("channel").with("Expected message 3")


Looks like ActionCable::TestHelper.capture_broadcasts might get you what you need. You might need to include ActionCable::TestHelper at the top of your test class.
messages = capture_broadcasts("channel") do
  function_i_am_testing()
end

assert_equal({ text: 'Expected message 1' }, messages[0])
assert_equal({ text: 'Expected message 2' }, messages[1])
assert_equal({ text: 'Expected message 3' }, messages[2])

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionCable/TestHelper.html#method-i-capture_broadcasts

You can use capture_broadcasts with rspec and get it down to: expect(messages).to eq ['first', 'second', 'third']

This looks suuuper nice and I would 120% go with it, but my project is on Rails 7.0.6, and this was added juuuuust a little later, in Rails 7.1.3... I might see if my team is willing to upgrade, lol.

Ah yes, the ole "too upgrade or not" question. Always a fun one. Hahaha

You can use the and matcher to chain multiple assertions:
expect { 
 function_i_am_testing
}.to(have_broadcasted_to("channel").with("Expected message 1")
 .and(have_broadcasted_to("channel").with("Expected message 2"))
 .and(have_broadcasted_to("channel").with("Expected message 3")))

